# How should the routing rules be for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/public

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /myproject/public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myproject/public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

**This code** works for me but it doesn't load files like **css, js** and it encounters **404** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched the subject with information from you. Routing rules with "HTACCESS" apply to Laravel. But there are actually threats. (Security). There is very important information in the settings file. (.env) Example: database user and password like...

We are not safe when we do not change the web root from the server. Thanks for contributing @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found the solution. Laravel users who do not use Homestead; Create a htaccess file to the public_html directory and run the code I gave in the answer. Now css, js, pdf, jpg, png briefly every file will work for you.

```
#new htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myproject/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It seems like you have your source files under the `public_html` directory. That's generally a security issue. If you're doing this in production you should instead treat `public_html` as your `public folder and rename any references to it in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the information you provided. But it cannot be accessed because it is "htaccess".